# Winforms TreeView scrollbar doesn't scroll all the way

Tags: winforms, treeview, scrollbar, vsto

I had in my WinForms application strange scrolling issue so I've tested the issue in a different project and then I saw a very strange behavior.

The issue: Scrollbar does not scroll all the way down - not showing the entire tree.

Normal behavior (separated project):
[image]

I've created a `Form` with simple `TreeView` when generating nodes everything works fine.

Strange behavior (my bug):
[image]

I've **copied** the `Form` (the *good* form) into a project I'm working on (VSTO application - Excel Addin) and changed **nothing!** you can see the above result - when scrolling down the whole `TreeView` the scrollbar allow you to see only down to somewhere in the middle of the `TreeView`.

Again, it's the **same** `Form` code for both screenshots but launched from different solutions (clean solution = good, my project solution = bad).

**My Question(s):**

What can cause this behavior?

What properties influence the size of the scrollbar for this control?

Where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after quite a time of searching the reason for that issue was the usage of an old DLL by another module in the project.
what solved this issue was:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```